# What is Team Flare's true goal?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

For some reason, I don't fully understand their intentions

What was Team Flare's true goal in the end? Was it to sell Pokemon, or to purge everyone (themselves not included)?

Comment: Why do your questions always have a -1? Is someone targeting you?

Comment: Team Flare's goal was to kill most humans and all Pokémon. Most humans, so making sure everyone's happy gets easier, all Pokémon to ensure noone abuses them for wars. At least, that's how I understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Massive spoilers ahead. Feel free to read after beating Team Flare.

> The goal was aquiring for them (**Team Flare**) all global resources. They want to do it by destroying the rest of pokemon and human world. They want to do that because they believe that there is too much pokemon and people and not enough resources to live happy together.

This Team Flare mindset was inspired by this (minor spoiler) problem...

> I connect this with problem that there was in minds of people in Europe in late XVIII and early XIX centuries called *[Malthusian cathastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusian_catastrophe)* link to wiki provided.

Answer (score 0):

Team Flare said that all humans and Pokémon do is fight and steal, so they sought to kill humans and all Pokémon to make the world beautiful. Thus, they made the ultimate weapon rise in hopes of killing all Pokémon and humans, but not the ones who were actually part of Team Flare.